# Subset dataframe with another dataframe of a different length

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, genome

I have a dataframe with interacting chromosomal pairs denoted by chromosome (chr), and position (pos) as follows:

```
>>>import pandas as pd

>>>df1
chr1     pos1     chr2     pos2
chr1    54278    chr13    68798
chr1    32145     chr7  1248798
... 
[162689366 rows x 4 columns]
```

In the real dataset, these are sorted by chr1, then pos1, chr2, pos2.

I have another dataset with the interacting pairs I wish to look at in the following format:

```
>>>df2
chr     start     stop     comment
chr1    54275    55080   cluster-1
chr1   515523   515634   cluster-2
...
chr13   68760    70760
...
[69 rows x 4 columns]
```

I wish to subset df1 to include rows if and only if both interacting pairs (chr1-pos1 & chr2-pos2) are found within the range of start and stop values in df2.

In this example, the final dataframe would look something like this:

```
>>>df3
chr1    pos1      chr2     pos2
chr1    54278    chr13    68798
...
```

I have been trying to do this step wise (for the first chr-pos pair, then the second) using the .between function in pandas without any success. I've tried in both python2.7 and python3.6.

```
>>>df3 = df1[(df1['chr1'].isin(df2.chr)) & df1['pos1'].between(df1.pos1(df2.start),df1.pos1(df2.stop))]
```

This seems to work for the .isin but I get an error for the .between function. I think because the dataframes are not the same length, but I can't be sure.

```
>>>df1['pos1'].between(df2.start,df2.stop)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2412, in between
    lmask = self >= left
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 699, in wrapper
    raise ValueError('Series lengths must match to compare')
ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone might have a more elegant solution, but in my head, I would join `df2` to `df1` twice, so that you get everything in one dataset, and comparisons are easy.

`df2` is basically a lookup table, and `df2.chr` should be matched to `df1.chr1` and to `df1.chr2` separately.

```
df_all = df1.merge(df2,
                   how='inner',
                   left_on='chr1',
                   right_on='chr') \
            .merge(df2,
                   how='inner',
                   left_on='chr2',
                   right_on='chr',
                   suffixes=('_r1', '_r2'))
```

Note the suffixes. So `pos1` will be tested to be in the `start_r1`-`stop_r1` range, and `pos2` will be tested to be in the `start_r2`-`stop_r2` range.

```
df3 = df_all[(df_all['pos1'] \
                  .between(df_all['start_r1'], df_all['stop_r1'])) &
             (df_all['pos2'] \
                  .between(df_all['start_r2'], df_all['stop_r2']))]

# Back to four original columns again
df3 = df3[['chr1', 'pos1', 'chr2', 'pos2']]
```